# Calling ctime twice produces same output with different inputs

Tags: c++, time

I have this simple piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    time_t now = time(0);
    tm timeDate;
    strptime("2023-2-10 15:03","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &timeDate);

    time_t time_input = mktime(&timeDate);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);
    char* dt2 = ctime(&time_input);

    cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;
    cout << "The input date and time is: " << dt2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

that should print those two dates. But I receive the same date according to which is processed first.

> The local date and time is: Fri Feb 10 15:03:00 2023  
> The input date and time is: Fri Feb 10 15:03:00 2023

or

> The local date and time is: Mon Feb 13 12:32:17 2023  
> The input date and time is: Mon Feb 13 12:32:17 2023

Comment: See [the manual on `ctime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime): *"Return value ... may be overwritten on each invocation"* Use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 5):

The `ctime` function is not reentrant, which means that you cannot safely call it multiple times and reuse the same output.
Instead, use the `ctime_r` function which writes its output into a buffer you supply and then the times will be different.